# I am trying to pass a method (which include a setState()) from a parent Stateful widget to child Stateless widget. But I am getting following errors

Tags: flutter, dart, state-management

I am new to Flutter and Dart, and I am creating a Flutter todo app for learning purposes.

I am trying to pass a method (which includes a `setState()`) from a parent Stateful widget to a child Stateless widget, but I am getting the following error: setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.

```
class TasksTile extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TasksTileState createState() => _TasksTileState();
}

class _TasksTileState extends State<TasksTile> {
  bool? isChecked = false;

  void checkBoxCallBack(bool? value) {
    setState(() {
      isChecked = value;
    });
  } //

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text('This is Task'),
      trailing: TaskCheckBox(
        isChecked: isChecked,
        toggleCheckBoxState: checkBoxCallBack,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TaskCheckBox extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool? isChecked;
  final Function(bool?)? toggleCheckBoxState;
  TaskCheckBox({this.isChecked, required this.toggleCheckBoxState});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Checkbox(
        value: isChecked, onChanged: toggleCheckBoxState!.call(isChecked!));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem will be solved by changing your `onChanged` to be a callback instead of directly calling the function.

```
Checkbox(
  value: isChecked,
  onChanged: (bool? value) {
    toggleCheckBoxState(value);
  }
)
```

Right now, you're creating the checkbox and, while creating it, you're immediately calling the function. Instead, you want this to only trigger once the user actually does something to the checkbox. Hence, a callback.